# Angular 2 CreateElement

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the statement of `document.createelement` in TypeScript but until now i could find a way to solve this problem is there are a way to create this function .

this is the component

```
import {Component,ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@Component({

selector: 'my-Calc',
  templateUrl:'./app/Calculator/calculator.component.html'
})
export class Calculator{
  tablerow:[1,2,3];
  calcItems :[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
}
```

this is my html template

```
<div>
  <table *ngFor="let tRow of tablerow">
<tr *ngFor=" let tItems of tablerow">
  {{tRow}}<td >{{tItems}}</td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to create a button element in each table box i have created 
by the way this is not the full code and thanks for help

Comment: Please show us what code you've tried, describe what problem you're actually trying to solve and also the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forloop on its td AND tr elements

```
<div style="border: outset; width:100px">
  <input type="text" #InputTxt style="width: 95px;">
  <br/>
  <table #Table style="border:solid black 2px;">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of columnNums">
      <td *ngFor="let col of row"  style="border:solid black 2px;"><input style="width: inherit;" type="button" (click)="Usednumber($event)" value="{{col}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

in the component:

```
columnNums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], ['+', 0, '/'], ['=', '-', '*']];
```

&inside the function:

```
 let v = e.toElement.defaultValue;
    this.inputTxt.nativeElement.value += v;

    if (v != '=') {
      if (v == '*' || v == '+' || v == '/' || v == '-') {
        this.op = v;
        this.inputTxt.nativeElement.value = '';
      }
      else {
        if (this.op) {
          this.num2 = this.inputTxt.nativeElement.value;
        }
        else {
          this.num1 = this.inputTxt.nativeElement.value;
        }
      }
    }

    else if (v == "=") {
      this.op2=v;
      this.calculate();
```

And This Is Best Idea I Have Got For Solving Such A Problem

Answer (score 1):

Syntax Mistake "document.createelement" 'E' Should be in capital letter.

correct:

```
<div>
      <table *ngFor="let tRow of tablerow">
         <tr *ngFor=" let tItems of tablerow"><
          {{tRow}}<td ><form><input type=submit value="click me"></form>{{tItems}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but this is javascript am looking for typescript

Comment: The `E` should still be capitalized. TS is a superset of JS.

Comment: If you show the code. We may help you because we are not able to see where you using 'document.createElement()'

Comment: i want to create a button in each table <td>

Comment: I want to generate this dynamicly